# MVC3 Range attribute - doesnt admit value zero

Tags: c#, attributes

I have the following attribute on my field:

```
[Range(-1,200)]
public decimal MyValue{ get; set; }
```

If I enter any value that doesn't fall in the range I get:

```
The field must be between -1 and 200
```

This is fine.

Here's the problem, I'm getting "The field must be a number" validation message when I enter zero which is a valid value.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be happening due to the `decimal` type. Try this:

```
[Range(typeof(Decimal),"-1", "200")]
public decimal MyValue{ get; set; }
```

[Source.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679255%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)